# Call class to another class

Tags: android

Good day, im creating a project about reminder/todo list with alarm manager.
i have 4 classes (AlarmManager,AlarmReceiver,MainActivity,NoteEditorActivity)

MainActivity - where all my reminders are listed

NoteEditorActivity - where i will create a reminder

now im adding a function for alarm to the noteeditor class.

my problem is how to call the AlarmManagerActivity class to the NoteEditor.

my AlarmManagerActivity and AlarmReceiver class are coded already. i just cant apply it normally.

AlarmManagerClass

```
package com.jayceejash.schedmeup;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class AlarmManagerActivity extends Activity{
private Button mStartBtn;
private EditText mTxtSeconds;
private Toast mToast;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mStartBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSetAlarm);
    mTxtSeconds = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSeconds);

    mStartBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
            {
    int i =    Integer.parseInt(mTxtSeconds.getText().toString());
    Intent intent = new  Intent(AlarmManagerActivity.this,AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent =       PendingIntent.getActivity(AlarmManagerActivity.this,2, intent,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+(i * 1000), pendingIntent);

                if (mToast != null)
                {
                    mToast.cancel();
                }
                mToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Alarm for activity is set in: " + i + "seconds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                mToast.show();
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                if (mToast != null)
                {
                    mToast.cancel();
                }
                mToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                mToast.show();
                Log.i("AlarmManagerActivity","NumberFormatException");
            }
        }
    });

}   
}
```

then my AlarmReceiver

```
package com.jayceejash.schedmeup;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.io.IOException;


public class AlarmReceiver extends Activity{
private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;
    Button stopalarm;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

PowerManager pm=(PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
mWakeLock =pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "my wakelock");
mWakeLock.acquire();
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON );

setContentView(R.layout.activity_stop_alarm);

//Stop the alarm music
stopalarm=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStopAlarm);
stopalarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     mPlayer.stop();
        finish();
        return;
}
});
PlaySound(this,getAlarmUri());
}


private void PlaySound(Context context,Uri alert){
mPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
try{
mPlayer.setDataSource(context,alert);
final AudioManager am=(AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if(am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM)!=0);
    {
        mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
        mPlayer.prepare();
        mPlayer.start();
    }
}
catch(IOException e){
Log.i("AlaramReciever", "no audio file");
}
}

//Get an alarm sound.  If none set, try notification, Otherwise, ringtone.
private Uri getAlarmUri()
{
Uri alert= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
if(alert==null)
{
    alert= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    if(alert==null)
    {
        alert=RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
    }
}
return alert;
}

protected void onStop(){
super.onStop();
 mWakeLock.release();

}
}
```

and this is my NoteEditorActivity Class

```
package com.jayceejash.schedmeup;

import com.jayceejash.schedmeup.data.NoteItem;
import com.jayceejash.schedmeup.R;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class NoteEditorActivity extends Activity {
    private NoteItem note;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_editor);
        }
        else {
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_editor_pre3);
        }

        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        note = new NoteItem();
        note.setKey(intent.getStringExtra(NoteItem.KEY));
        note.setText(intent.getStringExtra(NoteItem.TEXT));

        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteText);
        et.setText(note.getText());
        et.setSelection(note.getText().length());
    }

    public void saveAndFinish(View v) {
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteText);
        String noteText = et.getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(NoteItem.KEY, note.getKey());
        intent.putExtra(NoteItem.TEXT, noteText);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            saveAndFinish(null);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        saveAndFinish(null);
    }



}
```

if you guys have a tutorial or same project that im developing please help me, im just new in android and im enjoying developing here. thanks a lot

Comment: use Intents to call Activity from an another one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to call one Activity from another one, you should use Intents. The Intent Provides Bundle objects through which you can pass state information.

for more information from

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

```
An intent is an abstract description of an operation to be performed. 
It can be used with startActivity to launch an Activity, broadcastIntent to 
send it to any interested BroadcastReceiver components, and 
startService(Intent) or bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int) to 
communicate with a background Service.

An Intent provides a facility for performing late runtime binding between the 
code in different applications. Its most significant use is in the launching of 
activities, where it can be thought of as the glue between activities. It is 
basically a passive data structure holding an abstract description of an action 
to be performed.
```